# Fastreport error in report of multiples reports

Tags: sql, delphi, macros, fastreport

I have created a report of multiple reports.
In the querys I use macros for the where clause.

```
select * from tbl1 where &conditions order by id
```

Individual reports work fine.
The report runs correctly. The problem arises sometimes when I want to create the multi-report with the statements.

```
frxReport1.LoadFromFile('report.fr3');
frxReport1.PrepareReport(False);
```

In PrepareReport, it informs

> SQL error... Token unknown ORDER

. Order corresponds to SQL "**order by**".

Seeing FDMonitor the macro is missing.

```
select * from tbl1 where order by id
```

ResourceOptions.MacroCreate and MacroExpand are set to True.

All embedded reports (at least 10) contain macros. some are correctly added to the multi report, some are not. Why?

I am using Delphi 10.3 and Fastreport 6.8 Enterprise
I wait for comments

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a group of reports need to be printed at the same time or displayed in one preview window.

FastReport has the means of adding a second report to the end of an already built report. The `TfrxReport.PrepareReport` method has an optional `ClearLastReport` Boolean parameter which defaults to `True`. This parameter, when `True`, clears the output from the preceding built report.

The following Pascal code shows how to build a batch of two reports:

```
frxReport1.LoadFromFile('1.fr3');
frxReport1.PrepareReport;
frxReport1.LoadFromFile('2.fr3');
frxReport1.PrepareReport(False);
frxReport1.ShowPreparedReport;
```

Answer (score 0):

How to fix the issue.
What you have to do is, to have full control of your individual reports in a single unified report, repeat this sequence with each of the reports.

```
Reporte: TfrxReport;  // multi report
```

...

```
rpt := TRptForm001.Create(Self); // Reports to process TRptForm001, TRptForm002..., TRptFormNNN

try       
  // Define filter report...
  rpt.ddFec := Date1;
  rpt.htFec := Date2;
  Rpt.Output := srStream; // The output is made to a TMemoryStream
   
  Rpt.Report;  // Run individual report

  Reporte.EngineOptions.DestroyForms := False;
  Reporte.EngineOptions.SilentMode := True;
  Reporte.EngineOptions.UseFileCache := True;
  Reporte.EngineOptions.UseGlobalDataSetList := False;
  Reporte.EnabledDataSets.Clear; // Delete any previous dataset
  Reporte.EnabledDataSets.Add(rpt.frxDBDataset1);  // Load dataset(s).(TfrxDBDataset)    
  Reporte.LoadFromStream(rpt.StreamRpt);  // Load stream generated in the rpt
  lOkPrepared := lOkPrepared and Reporte.PrepareReport(lFirst);
finally
  Rpt.CloseData;  // Close the datasets (TFDQuery) of the current report (001, 002, nnn)
  Rpt.Free;
end;
```

In the individual report, Rpt001, 002, nnn do

```
  case FOutput of
      srStream:
        begin
          lClose := False;  // Dont close (TFDQuery)
          FStreamRpt := TMemoryStream.Create;
          frxrptIndMed.SaveToStream(FStreamRpt);
          FStreamRpt.Position := 0;
        end;
```

Finalmente

```
Reporte.ShowPreparedReport;
```

In this way, you can unify complex reports with data processes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).